# Facebook Scrape Information- Response code 206 error

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

I used facebook comment plugin.When I wrote the following meta tags on my html page.I am using Codeigniter frame work for my application.

```
 <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
          xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
          xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

    <head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object#">

      <meta property="fb:admins" content="{MY_FB_ID}"/>
      <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{MY_APP_ID}" /> 
      <meta property="og:type"   content="website" /> 
      <meta property="og:url"    content="{my url}" /> 
      <meta property="og:title"  content="beyondandameter" /> 
      <meta property="og:image"  content="http://mysitedomainname/Andameter/uploads/tech1.jpg" />
```

Scrape Information

```
Response Code:  206
Fetched URL:    http://mysitedomain/Andameter/anda/politics_pics/26
Canonical URL:  http://mysitedomain/Andameter/anda/politics_pics/26
```

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

```
Inferred Property:  The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Small og:image: All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions, with 1500x1500 preferred. (Maximum image size is 5MB.) Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.
```

is there anybody help me? where is my mistake?

Comment: The 206 is not an error, it just means that Facebook only requested the first x bytes from your server and it responded with partial content according to that. But your document does not contain the meta tags you mentioned when view over the mentioned URL.

Comment: I am not getting clearly, Tell me more details and where I will change my code.

Answer (score 0):

i would remove

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# object: http://ogp.me/ns/object#">
```

start at the

206 prob stay but  the other errors would be fixed
the image needs to be bigger than  what it tells you,  try like 600x400 px
you can add more than  one  image tag  just repeate the line and replace the image url
you could also add a description

hope that helps